# Blade: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, php-7

sometimes $structures array has the null value the same code for other variable is working fine but not in this case.

`@foreach($structures ?? [] as $item)
    {{ $item }}
@endforeach`

Comment: I don't think foreach works that way. Add an if before the foreach instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding `()` around `$structures ?? []` expression.

`@foreach(($structures ?? []) as $item)
    {{ $item }}
@endforeach`

Comment: I just need an empty array if the value of the `$structures` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forelse`  instead of `foreach`

```
@forelse ($structures as $item)
{{ $item }}
@empty 
No Items found.
@endforelse
```

The `forelse` check the condition as below.

```
@if ($structures->count())
  @foreach ($structures as $item)  
 {{ $item }}
  @endforeach
@else
No Items found.
@endif
```

Comment: This is useful but I don't want to empty condition in my code, In that case, it will look bad with empty `@empty` condition.

Comment: even `@forelse` gives the same error. Invalid argument supplied for ...